# jQuery - why ajaxForm bypasses the validation procedure?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      // bind 'regFormBody' and provide a simple callback function
      $('#regFormBody').ajaxForm(function() { 
          alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
      }); 

      // validate the #regFormBody form when it is submitted
      $("#regFormBody").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) { 
          alert('form is submitted');
        },        
        rules: {
          ...
        },
        messages: {
          ...
        }
      });
}
```

The problem is that after I add the

```
    // bind 'regFormBody' and provide a simple callback function
    $('#regFormBody').ajaxForm(function() { 
        alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
    });
```

The form validation doesn't work at all. I always see the message alert('form is submitted') even without entering any information to form.

May you tell me how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you swap the order and `.validate()` runs first?

Comment: Please post a live example for us to test with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand your [options object for `.ajaxForm()`](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object), like this:

```
$('#regFormBody').ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function() {
    return $('#regFormBody').valid();
  },
  success: function() { 
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  } 
});
```

This will kick off validation before submitting, and if it's not [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) it'll stop the submit from happening like you want.